# Error while installing composer on symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

This was the result that I get when I ran `composer install` to update composer dependencies and I've removed composer.lock to make sure updated dependencies will be downloaded.

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!  Fatal error: Declaration of App\Middleware\EventBusMiddleware::handle($message, callable $next) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\MiddlewareInterface::handle(Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope $envelope, Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\StackInterface $stack): Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope in /var/www/html/src/Middleware/EventBusMiddleware.php on line 8
!!
!!  In EventBusMiddleware.php line 8:
!!
!!    Compile Error: Declaration of App\Middleware\EventBusMiddleware::han
!!    dle($message, callable $next) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Mes
!!    senger\Middleware\MiddlewareInterface::handle(Symfony\Component\Messenger\E
!!    nvelope $envelope, Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\StackInterface $s
!!    tack): Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Can someone help me with understanding this error?

Comment: from what you pasted here it seems like you are using a version of the  symfony/messenger package that is not compatible with the code declared in the EventBusMiddleware. You should check your composer.json to look for dependencies, or if is code made by you, update the declaration of the handle method accordigly to the declaration of the interface.

Comment: yes, it seems out composer install was getting one bundle version incompatible with EventBusMiddleware . Thanks for help. :)